# Existence of model of ZF in which every uncountable cardinal is the cardinality of some power set?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Does there exist a model of ZF in which any uncountable cardinal number is equal to the cardinality of the power set of some set ?

( In ZFC it is not possible as is shown by the answers to this [cardinal numbers and the power-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576883/cardinal-numbers-and-the-power-set) , so I am asking only for a model of ZF  )

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "other than the continuum"?

Comment: You probably mean $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$. Since every model of $\sf ZFC$ is also a model of $\sf ZF$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : yes , but any model of $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$ is also a model of ZF :)

Comment: Yes. But if you ask about arbitrary models of ZF, then models of ZFC are also included, and then the answer is no as witnessed by the linked question's answers (regardless to the fact the arguments actually follow through ZF, by various properties of well-ordered sets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

For two main reasons:

1. Even in the absence of choice $\aleph_\omega$ cannot be a power set of anything. The proof is the same usual proof that relies on Koenig's theorem, which may require choice, but it does not require choice if the power set is well-orderable.

   So in any case it is provable you will have uncountable cardinals which are not power sets of anything.

But those are just singular cardinals, let's assume every *regular* cardinal is a cardinal of a power set. Which is a segue to the second reason,

2. If $\aleph_1$ is a cardinality of a power set, then it is necessarily the continuum. Moving to $\aleph_2$, then it has to be the cardinal of a power set, so it has to be the power set of $\omega_1$. Continuing by induction we get that the power set of an ordinal is well-ordered, and that implies choice over $\sf ZF$.

Comment: Okay so you are saying $\aleph_{\omega}$ is not a power set cardinal , can be proved without choice ?

Comment: It's exactly the same proof as with choice. $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be equal to $\aleph_\omega$ again. Now if $\aleph_\omega$ is the cardinal of a power set, then it has to be a power set of some $\omega_n$ for some $n<\omega$. But this means that $$\aleph_\omega\leq\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}\leq \aleph_\omega^{\aleph_n}=(2^{\aleph_n})^{\aleph_n}=2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_\omega.$$

Comment: 'Every regular cardinal is the cardinal of a power set' seems very strong e.g. it implies 'no strongly inaccessible cardinals' (doesn't it?) Perhaps a better axiom would be 'every successor cardinal is the cardinality of a powerset' which, by the argument you sketch here, seems to be equivalent to GCH.

Comment: @goblin: Sure, whichever you prefer. The outcome is the same.

Comment: @goblin. "Every regular cardinal is a power cardinal" is not especially strong.  The existence of an inaccessible cardinal implies the existence of a set-model for  ZFC +V=L, so  Con (ZFC)$\to$ Con (ZFC+V=L+"No Inaccesibles")$\to$ Con (ZFC+GCH+"No Inaccessibles").

Comment: @user254665: I think goblin meant that requiring every regular uncountable cardinal to be a power set is enough to disprove the existence of inaccessible cardinals. So he suggested a change which will be compatible with large cardinals axioms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila.  Thanx.I think u r right.

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on Asaf's claim that $\aleph_\omega$ cannot be a power set.  Suppose $|P(X)|=\aleph_\omega$ for some set $X$.  Since $|X|<|P(X)|$, $|X|<\aleph_\omega$, and so $|X|=\aleph_n$ for some $n<\omega$.  It would then follow that $$\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_n}=(2^{\aleph_n})^{\aleph_n}=2^{\aleph_n^2}=2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_\omega.$$

But by [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$.  While König's theorem in general involves the axiom of choice, choice is not needed here since all the sets involved in this application are alephs and hence come with a canonical well-ordering.

Comment: Haha! I *just* wrote this same equation in a comment. :-)