# Is all uncountable set is equipotent to a certain $\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Tags: set-theory

Can we say that every uncountable set $X$ is equipotent to the set of all the parts of a certain set $A$ ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but it seems to me that this kind of rests on the continuum hypothesis, no?

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576883/cardinal-numbers-and-the-power-set which asks a fairly different question but some of the answers still address your question.

Comment: The linked question has a few details, but in brief: There are cardinals, such as $\aleph_\omega$, that are not power sets (so, the answer to your question is no). In fact, we cannot even prove that any uncountable set of reals has the same size as the reals (this is the continuum hypothesis, whose failure is consistent with the usual axioms of set theory).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Building on Andres' comment, the relevant theorem is [Konig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Nifty!  Thanks!